# using the main function to display only the odd numbers in a list

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a list that only displays the odd numbers between 1 and 12, but I have to use the def main function. I have looked all over and have tried everything I could. I'm not sure why, but I've always had trouble using the def main function. Here is where i'm at now with my program.

```
print("I will display the odd numbers between 1 and 12.")

def main( ):

    for num in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]:

        odd = num[::2]

main( )

print (odd)
```

Anyone have any advice or see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have experience programming in other languages, or are you new to programming as well?

Comment: Completely new to programming overall.

Comment: The main function has nothing specific in Python, you can even name your main function whatever you like. Your problem would be the same with any function.

Comment: [_The Python Tutorial_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) is a very good introduction to the language.  You specifically need to read (or review) section [4.6. Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and 4.7, farther down that same page.  The typical way to call the `main` function is in an `if` block at the very bottom of your `.py` file, described in the library docs, "[29.4. `__main__` --- Top-level script environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. Start by getting rid of your `for`-loop, because what you want to do is to assign the list `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` to the variable `num`, not iterate over the individual numbers in the list.
Then you'll notice that `num[::2]` actually gives you the even numbers, so change that to `num[1::2]`. Lastly, you have to move `print (odd)` inside the `main` function, because the variable `odd` is only defined within that function.

The end result should look like this:

```
def main():
    print("I will display the odd numbers between 1 and 12.")
    num = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    odd = num[1::2]
    print (odd)
main()
```

---

If you want to keep the loop, you'll have to check each number individually and append it the list of odd numbers if it's odd:

```
odd = [] # make an empty list
for num in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]: # for each number...
    if num % 2: #...check if it's odd with a modulo division
        odd.append(num) # if yes, add it to the list
print(odd)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the for-loop?

Comment: @tmoKSU: Yes, but it's more complicated that way. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python implicitly defines the `main()` function, unlike C++ and some others. The problem in your code is not in the definition of `main()`. If you read the error message:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

you may get an idea that something is wrong with types. With the code snippet you've provided, you're iterating over a list of numbers (Python has a function `range()` specifically for the purpose of generating a sequence of numbers) and with each iteration, the number (type `int`) is stored in the variable `num`. And you're trying to use slicing, which is made for iterables. `int` is not an iterable. You don't need a for loop in your case. This will do the trick:

```
print("I will display the odd numbers between 1 and 12.")
num = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
odd = num[1::2] # first index is one to get the odd numbers
print(odd)
```

Comment: I think you meant "Python does _not_ implicitly define the `main()` function...".  It doesn't exist until the programmer defines it explicitly.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase No, it always exists. That's why Python code does not require an explicit definition

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Try it:  Open up a `python` or `python3` interactive session and type `main()`.  You'll get a `NameError`, because `main` does not exist unless you create it.  It's just a function, like any other (and _unlike_ C or Java, where the name "main" has special significance).  Were you thinking of the string [`'__main__'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html), which gets assigned to `__name__` when executing as a script?

Answer (score 0):

well you have much to learn, but in this particular case you use the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function to get the numbers, and even make it more general by asking the user for a number with [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), like this

```
def odd_number(n):
    print("I will display the odd numbers between 1 and",n)
    odd = list(range(1,n+1,2))
    print(odd)

def main():
    n = int(input("choose the max number to display odd number: "))
    odd_number(n)

odd_number(12)
main()
```